# SQL Select ALL ROWS but only if column value is unique

Tags: sql, count, subquery, where-clause

If I do the following:

```
select * from myTable
```

I get:

```
Column 1  | Column 2
---------------------
1         | Create
1         | Delete
2         | Create
3         | Create
4         | Create
4         | Delete
5         | Create
```

I want to perform a select statement where I only pull the rows that have a unique number for column 1

In otherwords I am looking for this result:

```
Column 1  | Column 2
---------------------
2         | Create
3         | Create
5         | Create
```

Not sure exactly how to pull this off with only one statement or if there even is a way to do that. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there are not duplicate `(column1, column2)` tuples, one option is `not exists`:

```
select t.*
from mytable t
where not exists (
    select 1 from mytable t1 where t1.column1 = t.column1 and t1.column2 <> t.column2
)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use aggregation:

```
select col1, max(col2) as col2
from t
group by col1
having count(*) = 1;
```

If there is only one row for a given value of `col1`, then `max(col2)` will be the value of the column on that row.

Answer (score 1):

A simple query to limit column #1 entires w/ a count not equal to 1.

```
SELECT col1, COUNT(col1), col2 
FROM myTable
WHERE count(col1) = 1
GROUP BY col1
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use group by =

```
select * from myTable where empno in (select empno val from myTable group by empno having COUNT(*) =1 )
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Select column1, column2 from (select column1, column2, count(column1) over (PARTITION BY column2) count
from myTable) where count = 1
```